# get_pixel function raises bus error: 10

Tags: c, macos, bus

```
    #include    <sys/types.h>
    #include    <sys/stat.h>
    #include    <sys/mman.h>    
    #include    <fcntl.h>
    #include    <stdio.h>   
    #include    <stdlib.h>  
    #include    <string.h>  
    #include    <unistd.h>
    #include    <limits.h>  
    #include    <pthread.h>

    #define FILE_MODE   (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

    #ifndef MAP_FILE    /* 44BSD defines this & requires it to mmap files */
    #define MAP_FILE    0   /* to compile under systems other than 44BSD */
    #endif

    #define SIZE 20

    #define N 3

    struct stat statbuf;

    struct pixel
    {
        char R;
        char G;
        char B;
    };

    char * src;
    int size;

    struct pixel *get_pixel(char *buf, int *pos)
    {
        struct pixel pix;
        struct pixel *ppix = &pix;
        ppix->R = buf[*pos];
        ppix->G = buf[(*pos)+1];
        ppix->B = buf[(*pos)+2];
        (*pos) += 3;
        return ppix;
    }

    void write_pixel(struct pixel *ppix, char *buf, int *pos)
    {
        buf[*pos] = ppix->G;
        buf[(*pos)+1] = ppix->B;
        buf[(*pos)+2] = ppix->R;
        (*pos) += 3;
    }

    void * do_rotation(void *rotation)
    {
        int fdout;
        char    *dst;
        char fich[SIZE];

        int counter,index, pos, x, y;
        int xmax = 0;
        int ymax = 0;
        int colormax = 0;

        /* Construção do nome do ficheiro de saída */
        sprintf(fich, "rot%d.ppm", *((int*)rotation));

        /* Zona #2 */

        if ( (fdout = open(fich, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,FILE_MODE)) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"can't creat %s for writing\n", fich);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* set size of output file */
        if (lseek(fdout, size - 1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"lseek error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (write(fdout, "", 1) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"write error\n");
            exit(1);
        }


        if ( (dst = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fdout, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"mmap error for output\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* Fim da Zona #2 */ 

        sscanf(src,"P6\n%d %d\n%d\n",&xmax,&ymax,&colormax);

        struct pixel imagem [ymax][xmax];

        for (counter=0, index=0; counter<3;index++)
        {
            if (src[index]=='\n')
                ++counter;
        }   
        pos=index-1;
        for (y=0;y<ymax;y++)
            for (x=0;x<xmax;x++)
                imagem[y][x] = *(get_pixel(src,&pos));
        pos=index;

        switch (*((int*)rotation))
        {
            case 0 :
                //Rotação 90º clockwise
                sprintf(dst,"P6\n%d %d\n%d\n",ymax,xmax,colormax);
                for (x=0; x<xmax; x++)
                    for (y=ymax-1; y> -1;y--)
                        write_pixel(&(imagem[y][x]),dst,&pos);
                break;
            case 1:
                //Rotação 180º
                sprintf(dst,"P6\n%d %d\n%d\n",xmax,ymax,colormax);
                for (y=ymax-1;y>-1;y--)
                    for (x = xmax-1; x>-1; x--)
                        write_pixel(&(imagem[y][x]),dst,&pos);
                break;
            case 2:
                //Rotação 270º clockwise
                sprintf(dst,"P6\n%d %d\n%d\n",ymax,xmax,colormax);
                for (x=xmax-1; x>-1; x--)
                    for (y=0; y<ymax;y++)
                        write_pixel(&(imagem[y][x]),dst,&pos);
                break;


        }

    /* Zona #3 */
        munmap(dst,size);
        close(fdout);
    /* Fim da Zona #3 */

        pthread_exit(NULL);

    }

    int get_stat(int fdin)
    {
        struct stat pstatbuf;   
        if (fstat(fdin, &pstatbuf) < 0) /* need size of input file */
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"fstat error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        return pstatbuf.st_size;
    }


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int id[N];
        int fdin, i;

        if (argc != 2)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"usage: trab11 <fromfile>\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ( (fdin = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"can't open %s for reading\n", argv[2]);
            exit(1);
        }

        size = get_stat(fdin);

    /* Zona # 1*/
        if ( (src = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fdin, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"mmap error for input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    /* Fim da Zona #1 */

    /* Zona #5 */
        pthread_t tid[N];
        for (i=0; i<N; i++){
            id[i]=i;
            pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, do_rotation, &id[i]);
        }
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
            pthread_join (tid[i], NULL);
    /* Fim da Zona #5 */

    /* Zona #4 */
        munmap(src,size);
        close(fdin);
    /* Fim da Zona #4 */

        exit(0);
    }
```

Every time I run this on Mac it gives me *Bus error: 10*, but if I run it on Linux it doesn't give me any error can someone give me a solution.

PS: The error is on `get_pixel` function but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: if possible, always try to put a mock code with simmilar functionality and **reduced** size

Answer (score 3):

In `get_pixel` you are returning a pointer to an automatic variable that will not exist when you exit the function here:

```
return ppix;
```

This declares an automatic variable:

```
struct pixel pix;
```

whose lifetime ends at the end of the function and therefore referring to that memory after you return from `get_pixel` is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can dynamically allocate using `malloc`:

```
struct pixel *ppix = malloc( sizeof( struct pixel ) ) ;
```

but you must remember to call `free` on the memory when you are done with it.

Comment: Actually `return pix;` might work just as easily... or rather, more easily.

Comment: nope its still not working the weird thing is that the code runs well on linux i dont understand why it wont run on mac

Comment: Undefined behavior means it may or may not work.  You've just been lucky (unlucky?) on Linux, because the compiler you used failed to catch your error, which could have happened for any number of reasons:  (it allocates automatic variables at word boundaries, so no bus error, or by sheer chance, it did so in this case.)  If your code is still not working after making the suggested change, then you have other problems, and should post a new code snippet, ideally a minimum snippet that gives you the error.)