# How do i run a program from the executable in its folder on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

Ok guys bear with me i'm a beginner. I was given a project to type input to an output file by my professor It works in windows cmd but i'm running it in Xcode and the file opens and works. But how do I use terminal to run the executable from its folder

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#define MAX_PATH 99

using namespace std;

void backUp();                //use this to copy the original array
void rowAvg1(int,int);
void rowAvg2(int,int);
void rowAvg3(int,int);
void avgAvg1(int, int);
void avgAvg2(int, int);
void avgAvg3(int, int);
void testAvg(int,int);
void swapLow(int,int);


int grades[5000][5000];  //array to store the original data
int work[5000][5000]; // backup the original data
double Avg1[500];     //to store the average of each student
double Avg2[500];    // average of each student ignoring the lowest two
double Avg3[500];
double classAvg[500];   //to store the averge of the class in each test
char *studentNames[5000];
string sn[50]={"Haris","Leon","Pete","Sam","Tenzin","Shabab","Zakia","Chen","Xiang","Mario","Lawrence","Kyle","Violet","Mary","Paolo","Joseph","Bill","Mario B.","Stephen","Lorraine","Harry","Nicholas","Ivy","James","Kenneth","Manuel","Novak"};

double a1;
double a2;
double a3;
int main()
{
    char filename[MAX_PATH + 1];

    cout << "Enter the filename along with the file format (e.g Grades.csv) :" <<endl;
    cin.getline(filename, MAX_PATH);
    ifstream file("Grades.csv");
    ofstream file2("ClassAverage.csv");



    char line[80], *p; // bigger than the length of a line, p is a string


////// Error check ////////

    if(file.fail()){
    cout<< "File could not be opened. The file name migh not correct." ;
}

    /////////// This loop reads the file line by line, parse it token by token ///////
    ////  and stores each token into a 2d array.   //////////




    int r=0;
    int c = 0;

    file.getline(line,79);

    while (!file.eof())
    {
    file.getline(line,79); // read next line
    p = strtok(line, ", "); // read first token
    studentNames[r]=p;


    if(file.eof())
        break;
    p = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    c=0;
    while (p != NULL) {

        grades[r][c++] = atoi(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, ", ");

    }

        r++;

}

backUp();     //copies the orginal data into work array

testAvg(r,c);    // claculates the average of each column

swapLow(r,c);    // finds and moves the two lowest grades to the end of the array

rowAvg1(r,c);    // finds the over all average grades of each student
rowAvg2(r,c);    // finds the over all average grades of each student ignoring the lowest two grades
rowAvg3(r,c);


//// Finds the average of the averages ////
avgAvg1(r, c);
avgAvg2(r, c);
avgAvg3(r, c);

////// Writes out the data to the file along with the averages /////
file2 << "Names,";

for(int j=1; j<=c; j++){
    file2 << "Test. " << j << "," ;

}
file2 << ",Average ,Avg ignoring lowest 1,Avg ignoring lowest 2" << endl ;


for(int i = 0; i<r; i++){

    file2<< sn[i] << ",";

    for(int j=0; j<c; j++){

        file2 << grades[i][j] << "," ;

    }
    file2<< "," << Avg1[i] <<"," << Avg2[i] << ", " << Avg3[i] << "\n";

}

file2 << "\nCLASS AVG,";

for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
    file2 << classAvg[j] << "," ;
}
file2<< "," << a1 << "," << a2 << "," << a3;  // prints out the average of the class averages and students averages.






file.close();
file2.close();

return 0;
}

////////////////////////////Function Definitions////////////////////////////////////////////

 void backUp(){
for(int r=0; r<5000; r++){

    for(int c=0; c<5000; c++)
        work[r][c] = grades[r][c];
}
}

    void rowAvg1(int x,int y){
int sum;
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

    sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<y; j++){

        sum += grades[i][j] ;
    }

    Avg1[i] = (double)sum/y;

}

 }

void rowAvg2(int x,int y){
int sum;
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

    sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<y-1; j++){

        sum += work[i][j] ;
    }

    Avg2[i] = (double)sum/(y-1);

    }
}


void rowAvg3(int x,int y){
int sum;
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

    sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<y-2; j++){

        sum += work[i][j] ;
    }

    Avg3[i] = (double)sum/(y-2);

}
}


void testAvg(int x,int y){
for(int j=0; j<y; j++){

    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){

        sum += work[i][j] ;
    }

    classAvg[j] = (double)sum/x;

}
}

void avgAvg1(int x,int y){

int sum=0;

for(int i=0; i<x; i++){


    sum += Avg1[i];
}
a1= (double)sum/x;
 }

 void avgAvg2(int x,int y){

int sum=0;

for(int i=0; i<x; i++){


    sum += Avg2[i];
}
 a2= (double)sum/x;
}

void avgAvg3(int x,int y){

int sum=0;

for(int i=0; i<x; i++){


    sum += Avg3[i];
}
a3= (double)sum/x;
 }



void swapLow(int x,int y){
int low1,low2;
int temp1,temp2;
int i,j;


    //// Moves the Second lowest to the end

for( i=0; i<x; i++){
    low1 = 0;
    temp1 = 0;
    for( j=0; j<y; j++){

        if(work[i][j]<work[i][low1]){

            low1 = j;

        }
    }
    temp1=work[i][low1];
    work[i][low1] = work[i][y-1];
    work[i][y-1]=temp1;

 }

//// Moves the Second lowest to the end
for( i=0; i<x; i++){
    low2 = 0;
    temp2 = 0;
    for( j=0; j<y-1; j++){

        if(work[i][j]<work[i][low2]){
            low2 = j;

        }
    }
    temp2=work[i][low2];
    work[i][low2] = work[i][y-2];
    work[i][y-2]=temp2;


}
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDacv.png)

Thats me running it in terminal from the executable file stored in Desktop as I would in windows cmd. Message that i get in Xcode console shows up asking me to type the file name but nothing happens when i do

Comment: Hi Kyle, Im not sure but it looks like from your screenshot that its a 'Bus Error' - which may be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492056/bus-error-10-on-mac-os-x) (the OP said his program was running fine on Linux but not Mac.  It may be an undefined behavior which is magically working on one system but not the other

Comment: "Bus Error, passengers dumped".  You'll need to run the code in a debugger.  From the terminal, `cd ~/Desktop; lldb name_of_program`.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies first off it was on windows and @trojanfoe so type cd ~/Desktop  "11db" then the name of my program ?